# Distance between a polygon and a point in mysql

Tags: mysql, function, polygon, distance, point

guys Please suggest me a mysql function to calculate distance between a point and a polygon.

I need a inbuilt mysql function for this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for [Functions for Testing Spatial Relations Between Geometric Objects](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html)

> The functions described in these sections take two geometries as input
>   parameters and return a qualitative or quantitative relation between
>   them.

From the manual:

> Note MySQL originally implemented these functions such that they used
>   object bounding rectangles and returned the same result as the
>   corresponding MBR-based functions. As of MySQL 5.6.1, corresponding
>   versions are available that use precise object shapes. These versions
>   are named with an ST_ prefix. For example, Contains() uses object
>   bounding rectangles, whereas ST_Contains() uses object shapes.
>
> As of MySQL 5.6.1, there are also ST_ aliases for existing spatial
>   functions that were already exact. For example, ST_IsEmpty() is an
>   alias for IsEmpty()

Comment: I searched a lot on google but did not find function , Can u please suggest the exact fuction or the query.